# Favourite Tags Numerical Keyboard Shortcuts Script

Tags: script

[image: A screenshot]

Another short and simple script, it adds numerical keyboard shortcuts to the favourite tags. Only works on those pages which have the favourite tags on them. The default modifier is <kbd>Alt</kbd> but the boolean expression at line 43 can easily be changed to some other modifier key combination.

Sorry to not provide a file for download but i am sure you will manage somehow, adjust includes as needed:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Favourite Tags Numerical Keyboard Shortcuts
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @include        *stackoverflow.com*
// ==/UserScript==

(function ()
{
    var cancelWaiting = false;
    jq_wait();

    function jq_wait()
    {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined')
        {
            window.setTimeout(jq_wait, 100);
        } else
        {
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
            window.setTimeout(function () { cancelWaiting = true; }, 5000);
            $(document).ready(favs_wait);
        }
    }

    function favs_wait()
    {
        var items = $("#interestingTags .post-tag");
        if (items.length == 0)
        {
            if (cancelWaiting) return;
            window.setTimeout(favs_wait, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            items.each(function (i, elem)
            {
                if (i <= 9)
                {
                    var x = 48;
                    if (i < 9) x = 49 + i;
                    $(document).keyup(function (e)
                    {
                        if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && e.altKey && e.keyCode == x)
                        {
                            window.location.href = $(elem).attr("href");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

---

**Edits:**

- Dreadful obi-wan...